# Verify if the set of solutions to a differentiable equation is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks to verify if the solution set to f''(x) = x is a vector space.
My solution was that it was not because if given some solution y, where y'' = x and some solution y2 where y2'' = x, it is not necessarily true that (y + y2)'' = x. Is this reasoning correct? and if so is this sufficient to prove it is not a vector space?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What matters is not that $(y+y_2)''$ is not necessarily $x$. It's rather that it is *never* $x$ (since it is equal to $2x$). Yes, that proves that the sum of any two elements of your space does not belong to it. But it is even simpler to note that $0$ does not belong to your space.